# Drupal 7, Views, Groups, and Feeds - Creating View for Feed Items in a Group

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-feeds

Before I get into the details, here is the overall goal:

I want to have a group of users which get access to a feed, and any new items that appear in that feed they will get access to as well.

Details:

I am using Organic Groups, Feeds/Feed Items, and Views. I have setup a single Organic Group and added a single user to it. I have taken a Feed and added it to the group as well.

I have tried a few different combinations of the queries for Views and here is where I am at currently: http://cl.ly/2T1a0s1A0j3A0I0d3i1u

There is a relationship setup between the Feed and the Feed Item. There is a filter setup that says if the user has permission to view the Feed they should be able to see the Feed Item.

However, when I login to the user account and visit the URL (which used to just be static and take no arguments, ignore the % I just added) I get a blank page.

It would be great to get some help figuring out this problem and/or some pointers on how to debug it + learn more about Views and how I could use Views/OG to solve this problem.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

The best way I did OG Groups was to create the group under content type. Once that is done. go back into content type and click on Feed scroll down to OG Groups tab click on it. You should seeNODE in the drop-down box and Groups in a select box below. Make sure node is clicked and Group is highlighted. Click save and now do the same for Feed Item.  There is one thing to be mindful of, when the feed imports, it will be bundled with the group however the feed it self will be separate from the nodes created linked only by the group. One way to make it easier to manage is to place the feed and the feed items into the same book when setting up the feed. It akes life much easier that way.